# How arrange dataset for multivariable classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, logistic-regression

My doubt is how i should prepare my training and label data for multivariable logistics regression, I tried to find on the web but most of the tutorials are using any library which do that job ,

So if my dataset looks like this:

```
input_data                                                     labels 


[ 'aa' , 'bb' ,'cc' ,'dd' , 'ee' ]                         ['n1' ,'n5']
['rr' , 'ff' , 'gg' , 'hh' , 'ii' ,'jj']                   ['g1', 'g5']
['kk' , 'll' , 'mm' , 'nn' , 'oo' , 'pp]                   ['y1','y2','y3']
['qq','rr','ss','tt','uu'vv','ww']                         ['y1','y2','z1','z2']
```

I bulild the vocabulary:

```
#building vocabulary

vocabulary = {'bb': 1, 'ff': 6, 'll': 12, 'hh': 8, 'rr': 18, 'tt': 20, 'gg': 7, 'vv': 22, 'jj': 10, 'nn': 14, 'qq': 17, 'kk': 11, 'cc': 2, 'mm': 13, 'ee': 4, 'ww': 23, 'ii': 9, 'oo': 15, 'ss': 19, 'uu': 21, 'pp': 16, 'aa': 0, 'dd': 3}

#building all labels list

labels =['y3', 'n1', 'g1', 'g5', 'y1', 'y2', 'n5', 'z1', 'z2']
```

Now next step I do padding of data:

```
# doing padding 


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,0 ,0 ]                             

[18, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,0]                              

[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,0]                    

[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,0]
```

All is ok yet , Now the confusion is how do i feed my labels to neural network, There are multi class associated with each input ,

Should i go with one-hot encoding method :

```
padded  input_data                                              one_hot labels 

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  0, 0]               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]    # ['n1' ,'n5']



[18, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,0]                [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    # ['g1', 'g5']


[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,0]        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]    # ['y1','y2','y3']


[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,0]   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]  #['y1','y2','z1','z2']
```

or second method is

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]     # [ ['n1'] , ['n5'] ]




[ [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]    # [ ['g1'] , ['g5'] ]



[ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] ]  # [ ['y1'] , ['y2'] ,['y3]]




[ [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]      #  [ ['y1'],['y2'],['z1'],['z2']]
```

or index method

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  0, 0]                                        [1, 6]

[18, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,0]                                      [2, 3]



[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,0]                              [4, 5, 0]

[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,0]                        [4, 5, 7, 8]
```

For single classification i used to take argmax from probability distributions like this:

```
probs  = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
preds  = tf.argmax(probs, axis=-1)   #which gives the max probality
```

distribution which is result

But in multiclassification how we will take result from distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For predicting the output, instead of just taking the maximum as in the single label problem, you need to define a threshold above which are all marked as 1.

Here is an example that illustrates for multi-label problem:

```
# Sample inputs
y_a = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], tf.float32)
y_b = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], tf.float32)
logits = tf.constant([[0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4]], tf.float32) 
# Threshold for classification
thres = 0.7

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y_a))
loss_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y_b))
#Probs
probs  = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
# a threshold of 0.5, tf.round() should help
acc_thresh_0_5 = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.round(probs), y_a), tf.float32))

# Variable threshold
binary_logits = tf.where(tf.less(probs, thres), tf.zeros(tf.shape(probs)), tf.ones(tf.shape(probs)))
acc_var_thresh = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.round(binary_logits), y_a), tf.float32))


with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(loss.eval())              #0.7136336
   print(loss_1.eval())            #0.89141136
   print(acc_thresh_0_5.eval())    #1.0
   print(acc_var_thresh.eval())    #1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for reply , sorry for confusion problem is multi labels , Not multi class , I tried to describe my problem here please answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285883/tensorflow-cross-entropy-for-multi-labels-classification

Comment: This is for multi-label classification, similar to what you have done in the above link , except that i have a variable threshold.

Comment: y_a is input and y_b are labels ? But why you are using softmax there when sigmoid is suggested by many ?

Comment: y_a and y_b are both labels, first is multi label and other is single label, just to compare the loss calculated using reduce_mean.

Comment: ok but i still didn't get use of softmax there , because many people are saying use sigmoid ( tf.nn.sigmoid) there ?

Comment: Sorry it should be sigmoid, edited, no softmax in multi-label